# How to make ionic-filter-bar list selectable

Tags: search, ionic-framework, jquery-ui-selectable

Im trying to use ionic-filter-bar ($ionicFilterBar)

Based on this

https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar

http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-add-a-search-bar-in-the-header-on-ionic/

Here is an example:

View
https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar/blob/master/demo/app/templates/main.html

Controller
https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar/blob/master/demo/app/scripts/app.js

How can I make it selectable action when I click a row ? Thanks